# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a laptop with a external display only

Tags: display, system-installation

I have a old Dell laptop that I use as a media computer hooked to my TV. It was in rough shape when it was given to me as it has a broken keyboard and screen. I have been using it with my TV or my spare monitor and a wireless keyboard/mouse with windows 7.

When I go to install Ubuntu the external screen turns off right away. My guess is that it is defaulting to the OEM screen which has now been removed. I have tried FN F7 on my external keyboard to swap screens but I have had no luck. I have wiped Windows I would rather Ubuntu but I did not expect this.

I was thinking of trying a different Disro but I have Ubuntu on 3 other computers

Thoughts?

Comment: I also have pretty much the same question for a Lenovo S10 netbook...

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Ubuntu via a different method.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

I'd suggest the network installer though I personally haven't tried it so far. Another option is the alternate CD. (If I recall correctly, it's only available for Lubuntu, but I've used it to install a system with KDE recently.)

I can't comment yet, so I'm kinda guessing here: You used a live CD or a live USB stick which booted alright to the desktop using the TV as a monitor. As soon as you clicked on the Install icon the TV went black?